# Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be a sequence of events. Show that...

Tags: probability

> Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be a sequence of events. Show that
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\leq P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}P(A_k). \tag{1}$$

I'm not sure at all I've done this correctly but I started by noting that

$$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_kP(A_k\cap A_{k-1}). \tag{2}$$

Noting that $a_k\leq n-1$ and plugging (2) into (1) I get

$$\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\leq P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P(A_k\cap A_{k-1})}_{=S},$$

What values does the last sum attain? Because if $S\geq 1$ and $n-1\geq0$ then it follows that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\leq P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P(A_k\cap A_{k-1})\leq \\ \leq \sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)-(n-1)\leq\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k),$$

and the double inequality is proven. But I don't see how a sum of probabilites can exceed 1. How can I improve upon my attempt?

Comment: The sum of probabilities can exceed 1 if they intersect. The sum itself isn't a probability.

Comment: Okay, but how do I know it's greater than or equal to 1? Is it even true in this case?

Comment: If you just have a sequence of events and no other information I don't see why their sum would need to be greater than 1, unless they cover all possible outcomes and intersect or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_{k}=A_{k}-(A_{n-1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{0})$ with $A_{0}=\emptyset$, then $P\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\right)=P\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}B_{n}\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(B_{n})\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(A_{n})$.

On the other hand, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(B_{k})&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(P(A_{k})-P(A_{k-1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{0}))\\
&=P(A_{1})+\sum_{k=2}^{n}(P(A_{k})-P(A_{k-1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{1}))\\
&\geq P(A_{1})+\sum_{k=2}^{n}(P(A_{k})-1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(A_{k})-(n-1).
\end{align*}

Comment: What exactly have you proven here? I don't understand the $B_k$.

Comment: I want to let $B_{n}$ to be disjoint, and its union is exactly the whole $A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's probably a great proof you've got there but my brain hurts, I don't understand what you're proving? And how can a sum or union go from $k$ to $n$? shouldn't it be $k=1$?

Comment: Do you understand it now that user edited it?